# Show only hours and higher units when subtracting timestamps (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Normally,

```
age(end, start)
```

outputs:

```
X days HH:MM:SS.SSSSSSS
```

Which you can use `date_trunc` to round the timestamp. For example:

```
date_trunc('second', end - start)
```

outputs:

```
X days HH:MM:SS
```

Now, the problem I have is I want an output in the format of:

```
X days HH hours
```

and when I use

```
date_trunc('hour', processed_timestamp_utc - start_time_utc)
```

this outputs

```
X days HH:00:00
```

What can I do to make it output

```
X days HH hours
```

or even

```
X months X days HH hours MM minutes
```

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `justify_hours()` ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
regexp_replace(date_trunc('hour', processed_timestamp_utc - start_time_utc)::text, ':00:00$', '');
```

Using `regexp_replace` you could also bring it to any of the other forms that you suggested.

Comment: This is great. Thank you!